# In Gtk, how do I center the text within a TextView vertically?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

If I just make a standard `TextView` with the `Justification` set to `Center`, it looks something like this:

[image: Center-Justified TextView]

If I also want to center the text vertically, as well as horizontally, how do I do this?

Comment: I don't see any way to do this "normally" with GtkTextView. You could probably subclass GtkTextView and override some of its text-drawing functions, but it may be quite difficult. I highly recommend asking in the GTK+ mailing list instead, since there are more people with relevant knowledge there.

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to fudge such an alignment by dynamically updating `pixels-above-lines` based on the size of the textview control and the size of the text being displayed in it.

Comment: By combining pixels-above-lines with either a mono-spaced font or drawing out the text to figure out how many lines it takes up you could automatically calculate what the value should be to center it (by comparing against the height of the TextView itself).

Comment: @minitech: I've long since moved on from this issue, and did not go back to investigate this solution. Since you placed the bounty on this question, did this solution work for you? I will accept the answer if it did.

Comment: @Matthew: No, I haven't figured out how to measure the text in it, but this is the most correct answer of them all, and I didn't want the bounty to go to waste :) I'll add a code sample when I get it, though.

Answer (score 4):

TextViews are normally meant for a large amount of text that the user can edit. As such it may grow too large and have to scroll, hence the difficulty with vertical centering.

If you're only using it to display a message that doesn't have to be edited, you might try `Gtk.Label` instead, which you can center vertically.

Comment: I see, I'm taking your advice for now and using Labels rather than TextViews. Eventually, though, I'd like for them to be able to be edited in-place. Hopefully there is some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
GTK_WRAP_CHAR
```

which can wrap the text at "every place a cursor can appear", as seen here: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-set-wrap-mode (click into it a bit)

That may be beneficial with

```
pixels-above-lines
```